# How to make SSRS report table transparent

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

i am using SSRS-2014 report for showing the table data but my table rows are having panels which are having background colors, because of that i am having one background image on report is not visible.

Is it possible that will make the table rows Panels color transparent which will keep the color of rows but still show the background image.

this is my table is SSRS Report and you can see broken line in that is actually a background image. which is coming between the row spacing.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can either have completely transparent text boxes or totally solid background colours.  You cannot have a see-through grey, for example.

If you want to set your textbox background colours to transparent, you need to set the background colour to either `No Color` or `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks but
i cant keep the row textbox background No color or Nothing

Comment: is it possible that i can put image on top of this which will be transparent so my table behind image will be display.

Comment: @Liquid If you are only exporting your reports to PDF format, maybe.  You would have to test how well SSRS handles transparency in embedded image files.  If you want your reports to be viewed online? No, this is not possible as report items cannot be rendered on top of one another when viewed as HTML.

Comment: No both are there online view and PDF.

Comment: @Liquid Then no, you cannot have an image on top of a table.